# how to check if object from current array exist in previous array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reduce

I have an array contain x array of object , my objective is to check if object from current array exist in previous array if not (object dose not exist in previous array) i will create it in that previous array .
the main array is like below :

```
    [
    {
    alphabet: [
     {value: 1, name: "X" },
     {value: 4, name: "Y" },
     {value: 1, name: "Z"}
    ]
   },
 {
   alphabet: [
     {value: 1, name: "W" },
     {value: 4, name: "X" },
     {value: 1, name: "Y"}
    ]
}
    ]
```

the inspected output is like this :

```
   [
{
    alphabet: [
     {value: 1, name: "X" },
     {value: 4, name: "Y" },
     {value: 1, name: "Z" },
     {value: 1, name: "W" }
    ]
},
   { alphabet: [
     {value: 1, name: "W" },
     {value: 4, name: "X" },
     {value: 1, name: "Y"}
    ]
    }
    ]
```

Comment: Your javascript here is not valid. please fix it

Comment: Why does `{value: 1, name: "W" }` turn into `{value: 0, name: "W" }` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms when i found that object and create it in the previous array i m gona change his value to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question well, you can use `spread` :

```js
let data =[
    {
    alphabet: [
     {value: 1, name: "X" },
     {value: 4, name: "Y" },
     {value: 1, name: "Z"}
    ]
   },
  {
   alphabet: [
     {value: 1, name: "W" },
     {value: 4, name: "X" },
     {value: 1, name: "Y"}
    ]
  }
];

console.log(
  {
    alphabet : [
      ...data[0].alphabet,
      ...data[1].alphabet.filter(a=>!data[0].alphabet.some(b=>b.name===a.name)),
    ],
  },
  data[1],
);
```